# Is it safe to store credentials in github secrets?

Tags: github, github-actions

[Github Secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets) provides a way for passing credentials to Github actions, but are they safe enough to be trusted with highly sensitive credentials?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that anyone can really answer that for you. I think it depends how sensitive, and what level of risk you can afford to take.

What I would suggest, if you are concerned about the security of your secrets, is not to use third party GitHub actions directly. Always fork the action and use *your fork* in workflows. This will prevent the possibility of someone modifying an action you are using to capture secrets and send them to some external server under their control.

Answer (score 0):

Secrets are encrypted environment variables that you create in an organization, repository, or repository environment. The secrets that you create are available to use in GitHub Actions workflows. GitHub uses [a libsodium sealed box](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes) to help ensure that secrets are encrypted before they reach GitHub and remain encrypted until you use them in a workflow.
For more details see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Add an additional layer of protection by adding org-level access policy and enable reviewer to control env secrets.